# List of special characters in the shell

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

I am not sure what they are called, but where could I find a list of wild cards?

I see things like:

- `$f`
- `%s`
- `$1`

Is there a definitive list for what each one represents?

Comment: @Danjel, `$f` is a reference to a variable. e.g If you had `f="value"` then you'd call the variable as `echo $f`. The `"%s"` in a parameter to `printf` which means `String`. The `$1` is the first positional parameter e.g `$1 $2 $3 etc...` See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100 for more.

Comment: Please clarify you question. If you want to know about wildcards just type `man 7 glob`. If you want to be familar with printf - use `man 3 printf`. Or if you want to get more info about passing variables in bash-scripting see `man bash`

Comment: @val0x00ff thank you for answering my question. I am glad you understood what I was talking about.

Answer (score 2):

These are not wild card characters. @val0x00ff already explained what they are.

To learn more about those just go through 
http://www.tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm

I guess you are new to all 3 -  unix, C and bash so I also recommend you to go through http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string and http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/Bash-Beginners-Guide.html